# How do i automate the branch/new team build process in TFS

Tags: .net, tfs, msbuild

We make a release branch from trunk at the end of each sprint.

This is a manual job; we branch the src and manually edit the build config.

This has proved to be an error prone process. Is it possible to automate it in TFS?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can automate in TFS using the .NET API.  This give you access to the [VersionControlServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.aspx) object for branching along with the [IBuildServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.ibuildserver.aspx) object for modifying your build definitions.

The following question might be useful when it comes to performing the branch in code.

[How to create a new source code branch using TFS API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559180)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the branch command of the tf command-line utility:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d73s8b27.aspx

I don't have any advice on editing the build config, though.

Answer (score 0):

Good question (the issue will hit me soon ;) ).

Several ideas (how I'll start):

- use a parameter as part of the path to solution/s, so you'll need to change just in 1 place instead of several
- branch build definition
- workspace should be reconstructed manually (at least from what I know now - we are using 2-3 TFS Projects in a workspace)
- override BuildNumber using BuildNumberOverrideTarget